# How to prevent spams from admin-ajax.php file?

Tags: wp-admin, comments, spam

I noticed today that a spammer is posting comments on my website using the `admin-ajax.php` file. Does this mean that my website is hacked?

If it is not hacked, how can I prevent that person from posting spam comments using this file?

Thanks.

Comment: it means you have an unsecured commenting admin AJAX endpoint, but that file doesn't have any commenting functionality, that has to be added by themes and plugins using the APIs. You would need to identify which plugin or theme provides AJAX comments as a feature, then contact their support routes. Otherwise there is nothing that can be done without knowing more information. It's very unlikely this means your website was hacked, and highly likely you're using a theme or plugin that is either poorly built, or misconfigured ( e.g. you let anybody comment in the settings )

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell :). The comment plugin I use does have an AJAX realtime comment system with custom comment form and fields.

Comment: That explains it then, you'll want to contact their support. I'd suggest to them supporting nonces so that they can only be submitted from a valid page/post. Or just turning off unauthenticated comments. There's a good chance though that the spammer is just filling out the comment forms as any other user would, and admin-ajax.php is showing because that's how that plugins AJAX works